# Not able to process data with PigStorage

Tags: apache-pig

I want a file to process with pig Script

My input file is this (`&` is column delimeter and `$` is row delimeter):

```
abc&bc&121&aa$aaj&jkj&print&star$aa&tss&jjlk&121
```

I tried this:

```
a = LOAD 'try.txt' USING PigStorage ('$') as (col1:chararray); b = FOREACH a Generate REPLACE(col1, '&', ',');
```

I am trying to separate a tuple after 1st delimeter but I am getting only 1st tuple using this.

Outputfile what I am looking for:

```
(abc,bc,121,aa)
(aaj,jkj,print,star)
(aa,tss,jjlk,121)
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi saurav, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please provide for us examples of anything you've tried already? This may help people to understand where you're stuck.

Comment: I tried this: a = LOAD 'try.txt' USING PigStorage ('$') as (col1:chararray); b = FOREACH a Generate REPLACE(col1, '&', ','); I am trying to separate a tuple after 1st delimeter but I am getting only 1st tuple using this. Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Put all of your trial attempts into your question, you can edit it with the `Edit` button :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

**Option1:**

**input**

```
abc&bc&121&aa$aaj&jkj&print&star$aa&tss&jjlk&121
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line,'$')) AS splittedLine;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(splittedLine,'&')) AS(col1,col2,col3,col4);
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(abc,bc,121,aa)
(aaj,jkj,print,star)
(aa,tss,jjlk,121)
```

**Option2:**

**PigScript:**

```
  A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('$') AS (row1:chararray,row2:chararray,row3:chararray);
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(STRSPLIT(row1,'&'),STRSPLIT(row2,'&'),STRSPLIT(row3,'&')));
  DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(abc,bc,121,aa)
(aaj,jkj,print,star)
(aa,tss,jjlk,121)
```